# Camera lookAt target changes when rotating parent node

Tags: math, opengl, camera, rotation

I have the following issue.I have a camera with lookAt method which works fine.I have a parent node to which I parent the camera.If I rotate the parent node while keeping the camera lookAt the target , the camera lookAt changes too.That is nor what I want to achieve.I need it to work like in Adobe AE when you parent camera to a null object:when null object is rotated the camera starts orbiting around the target while still looking at the target.What I do currently is multiplying parent's model matrix with camera model matrix which is calculated from lookAt() method.I am sure I need to decompose (or recompose ) one of the matrices before multiplying them .Parent model or camera model ? Anyone here can show the right way doing it ?

UPDATE: The parent is just a node .The child is the camera.The parented camera in AfterEffects works like this: If you rotate the parent node while camera looks at the target , the camera actually starts orbiting around the target based on the parent rotation.In my case the parent rotation changes also Camera's lookAt direction which IS NOT what I want.Hope now it is clear .
UPDATE1:
I use GL 4.0 , no fixed pipeline and all my math is done manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was with view and model matrices state.I mistakenly inverted view matrix after its position vector was already negated.So the right thing was just to multiply parent node model matrix with camera view matrix and that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is not a scene graph; there are no objects, *there is no camera!* gluLookAt is not even OpenGL, it's just a helper function and it has no awareness of any transformation hierachy applied whatsoever. Since OpenGL doesn't deal with a scene and the glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix give a false feeling something bigger going on, you might have been lured into thinking about it in a wrong way.

It is *your* responsibility, to do all the math you expect. Here's what you do:

1. You should no longer use the OpenGL fixed function matrix manipulation methods. They're deprecated and have been removed from later versions of OpenGL!
2. Implement a fully functional scene graph. Use feature complete matrix math libraries for this. Most importantly you'll need a method to determine the transformation (matrix) between any two nodes in your transformation hierachy tree. The most straightforward approach is from the starting and target noded to do right-associative multiplication while traversing to the top, until a shared ancestor node is reached. Then you multiply the inversed target node transformation composition on the transformation composition from the starting node. The result is the transformation between them.

Now that you can determine transformations between nodes you have the tool to do the proper look at operation within the space defined by that transformation.

Comment: Ok ok , my bad ,haven't mentioned that. I KNOW , and I DO all the math manually.using GL 4.0  , no fixed stuff :) Also you probably missed the point of my problem .I have a perfectly working scene graph system for regular nodes (parent to child etc).But for the camera parenting scenario I need it working slightly differently.So the parent rotation shouldn't rotate the camera node but orbit it around the target.That is how it works in AfterEffects.

Comment: Actually never used fixed pipeline :P